# How to Save Print version of HTML for the current Page Server side

Tags: asp.net, printing

I have some pages that I want to save the PRINT version of the HTML that the browser would render. I need to do this server side, because I want to convert it to a PDF and them embed it in an email.
These pages I want to print have the following in the header of their Master Page.

```
<link media="all" href="../css/stylenav.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link media="screen" href="../css/stylescreen.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link media="print" href="../css/styleprint.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

When I do the following I get the HTML for the Screen Version. I need the Print Version. Can this be done?

```
Dim url As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
'Prepare Request
Dim request As System.Net.WebRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url)
request.Method = "GET"
request.ContentType = "text/html"
'Execute the request
Dim response As System.Net.WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
'Read data 
Dim ResponseStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
'Write content into the MemoryStream
Dim resReader As New BinaryReader(ResponseStream)
Dim docStream As New MemoryStream(resReader.ReadBytes(CInt(response.ContentLength)))
Dim doc As New Document(docStream)
'Save document
doc.Save("out.pdf", SaveFormat.Pdf, SaveType.OpenInApplication, Page.Response)
```

Thanks.

Edits:
Here is some more details.
I am using the ASPOSE Library to convert the stream to a document and then PDF. This part works fine, but it is not what gets printed.

Comment: I don't think the problem lies within the posted code. Your `HttpWebResponse` contains the same HTML that a browser will see - including links to three stylesheets. You must be doing something later in your code to render til HTML to PDF, and in that you seem to incorrectly choose the `screen` media rather than the `print` media.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass a parameter to your page and swap the screen PDF for the print PDF in code, otherwise you'll still end up with the screen version regardless. Don't target the medium in this case, just use the print stylesheet instead.

Comment: I will try this. Since all the pages use the same master page, this may work. I just need to see how to modify these css links.